# SharePoint 2013 Enterprise On Premise Apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to install Apps from the MS Store to my on-premise SharePoint 2013  installation. I do not want them connecting to the outside world once installed. However the terms and conditions always seem to say that the app "may" connect to the internet without warning me. How can I be sure that any App I install truly is stand-alone. Or do all Apps "phone home"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The farm actually 'phones home' in order to validate licensing of Apps (free or not). You'll need outbound TCP 80/443 for farm members.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess I'll have to give them a miss then.